# How to Refresh a .php Page After Form Submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

This seems to be pretty basic but I've looked at all the suggestions (online) I can find -- and they did not work -- so I thought I might as well ask the Stack-Community.

I simply want my page to refresh AFTER the form is submitted.

I have my php Session Header first on the .php page:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
$_SESSION['username'] = '';
header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 }

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}else {
    echo "Wrong username or password.";
}
}
```

I then have a form start code:

```
     <form action="" method="post" >
```

I have used different inside the action " " but these don't seem to work.

I also then have a input type " " that looks like this:

```
     <input type="submit" name="submit_invoice" value="Submit" />
```

However, nothing I alter in this makes the page load AFTER the form is submitted.

Here are some of the things I've tried on either the FORM or the INPUT TYPE areas OR after the query to update the mysql record in the DB.  Please Note: I am able to update the data in the DB so the code is working . . . but nothing seems to work.  I must be doing a little thing wrong.

```
     header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
     location.reload();
```

When I use header() the error is that the header is already set up so can't do it again.  Location reload simply does not reload.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: If your form use a post method and have a submit button (without any js) it is already refreshing, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: `location.reload` is javascript, not PHP. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript which blocks the submit button from firing the event?

Comment: What does the developer console's network tab show when you click the submit button? It doesn't initiate a new request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
die('<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">');
```

Comment: Won't this just put the user into an infinite loop? You're redirecting to the same page everytime..

Comment: I have a form that has DB values, and I'm looking to update the form.  I'm looking to reload the page with the revised / updated information.  If I refresh the page in the browser, the data is updated.  With your code, James, it does send me to same page but not with the value int he "?id=value" statement.  I also have an error pop up but the page changes too quickly for me to see it.

Comment: Yes. But that can be locked if you need no more refresh. If you want to return the page, you can send an input [type = "hidden"] the url of the page, and dynamically change the header ("Location")

Comment: Perfect.  I just added a session value and it worked.  Thanks so much.